# insert raw svg into page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page successfully asking for and parsing some raw SVG from a JSON object. The problem is taking that SVG and putting it into a page. I have:

```
function addSVGToPage(SVGToAdd) {
    var entry, decodedEntry;
    makeAJAXCall(SVGToAdd, function (returnedJSON) {
        var svgElement;
        entry = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(returnedJSON.data.content.replace(/\s/g, ''))));
        decodedEntry = entry.split('\n').slice(2).join('\n');  //remove the first two elements in the file that prevent them from being added as an actual file.

        $(insertArea).append(decodedEntry);  //insertArea is a <div>
    });
}
```

But it does not seem to putting anything on the page.

What is the best way to go about putting the returned SVG (as a string) on to the page?

Edit: **Solution!**

The solution is that (due to security or namespce, IDK) you need to parse the raw string as a XML then import it into the DOM. As below

```
function addSVGToPage(SVGToAdd) {
    var entry, decodedEntry, xmlDoc, importedNode;
    makeAJAXCall(SVGToAdd, function (returnedJSON) {
        var svgElement;
        entry = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(returnedJSON.data.content.replace(/\s/g, ''))));
        decodedEntry = entry.split('\n').slice(2).join('\n');  //remove the first two elements in the file that prevent them from being added as an actual file.
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(decodedEntry); // turn the string into an xml fragment

        importedNode = document.importNode(xmlDoc.documentElement, true);
        document.body.appendChild(importedNode);
    });
}
```

Did not end up using the d3 method, although it was a good one, because the data coming back was JSON containing a base64 encoded string of the SVG (plus some extra declaration stuff) and jQuery capable of handling that without adding in an extra library.

Edit 2:
For those interested: http://dougmiller.github.com/SVG-Shapes is the link to where it is set up.

Comment: do you inspected DOM using some debug console after this piece of code ?

Comment: yarp, it is as if the html is untouched by this at all.

Comment: sooo ... do you recieved any data at all ? try to step code using console

Comment: Definitely receive the data. Logging to console will show that it is there.

Comment: and what about second option ( step thru code with jQuery for development ? )

Comment: did last line works if you explicitly put some simple svg into `decodedEntry` ?

Comment: jQuery doesn't work well with svg in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_xml) has nice means of doing this:

```
d3.xml("tuto3.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
   var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
}
```